# Webpack 5 support for SharedWorkers?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, web-worker, shared-worker

I want to use SharedWorkers with my React-App. As stated in the docs (https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/), Webpack 5 supports Web Workers in general. So it should also support SharedWorkers as one implementation of Web Workers.

The shown example works as expected:

```
new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));
```

But if i change the line to

```
new SharedWorker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));
```

nothing happens. The worker code does not get executed and no error is shown in the console.

Can someone help me getting Shared Workers working with Webpack 5 (using CRA and react-scripts 5.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem, what works for me is to put the worker.js file under the public folder, and then this connection works

```
new SharedWorker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));
```